# mysql count occurrences of special character in a field

Tags: php, mysql

I am wanting to count all occurrences of the @ symbol in a field and originally i thought **LIKE '%@%'** would be the way to go, but if the character appears in the field more than once it only counts it as one.

What other method are there that i could use that would count every occurrence?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
For anyone needing it, this is what i ended up using that works.

```
$count = 0;
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT LENGTH(field_name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(field_name,'@','')) AS 'occurs' FROM table_name WHERE field_name LIKE '%@%'");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $count += $data['occurs'];
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: Count the difference between the length of the string and the length of the string with @ replaced by ''

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
select length('aa:bb:cc:dd')-length(replace('aa:bb:cc:dd',':',''));
```

source: http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/215049

Comment: I don't understand how to use that? i'm using php btw.

Comment: select length('aa@bb@cc@dd')-length(replace('aa@bb@cc@dd','@',''));

Comment: I still don't understand, what are the a,b,c, and d's?

Comment: just replace 'aa@bb@cc@dd' with the field name, it's basically counting the length of the string - the length of the string without the '@'

Comment: so like this? ("SELECT length(field_name)-length(replace(field_name,'@','') FROM table_name")

Comment: That gives me **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM table_name' at line 1**

Comment: you're missing a ), should be SELECT length(field_name)-length(replace(field_name,'@','')) FROM table_name

Comment: Yeah i just spotted that lol, but it now only returns **Resource id #25**

Answer (score 0):

You could make this even simpler by using the ``substr_count function in php. see below.

```
$message = $row['themessage'];
echo substr_count($message, '@');
```

what this will return is the number of times @ has occurred in your "themessage" field in your database.