# Return records where favorite colors are not all excluded

Tags: mysql, mariadb, where-clause

mysql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03f4e72

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `favorites` (
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `colors` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `favorites` (`name`, `colors`) VALUES
  ('Timmy', 'blue,yellow,green'),
  ('John', 'green,orange,black'),
  ('Alysha', 'red,purple,orange'),
  ('James', 'yellow,green'),
  ('Janet', 'reen'),
  ('Peter', 'purple,orange,blue'),
  ('Ryan', 'purple'),
  ('Tony', 'blue,red');
```

I want to return records based on colors I exclude, for example, if I exclude purple, all but Ryan's record would return.

If I exclude yellow and green, all but James would return.

If I excluded orange and black, all records would return, the reason John would return with the rest of the records is because while he has orange and black as his favorite colors, he also likes green, which was not excluded.

It's a silly way of going about this and I know the favorite colors should be stored in another table, but the table structure can not be changed and I am trying to accomplish this using pure sql

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use `FIND_IN_SET()` to test values in a comma-separated list.

Comment: I am having a hard time trying to understand how this would work in my situation

Comment: `WHERE NOT ( FIND_IN_SET(colors, 'yellow') AND FIND_IN_SET(colors, 'green') )` will exclude yellow and green.

Comment: select * from favorites WHERE NOT ( FIND_IN_SET(colors, 'yellow') AND FIND_IN_SET(colors, 'green') ) 

returns James, I was expected all records except James to return

Comment: Yeah, realized afterward that you want to exclude exact matches of all, not subsets. So you also have to count the number of items in the list, and only exclude it's the same as the number of colors you're excluding.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922962/mysql-count-occurrences-of-special-character-in-a-field for how to count the number of `,` in the list. Add 1 to get the number of items in the comma-separated list.

Comment: possible to sort colors by alpha order? if so, I can do an exact match on it and return true or false

Comment: so a record where it is: green,blue would be sorted: blue,green

Comment: Yes, if you sort them then just use `WHERE colors != 'green,yellow'`

Comment: do you know how it is possible to sort a string like green,blue in sql to be blue,green?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172996/mysql-sort-comma-separated-string-in-column